# Outlook Textbox Value update and not replace

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook, outlook-2010

I have used a custom form in `Outlook` as task management. I would like to ask how can resolve the following problem that i have.

When someone open new task i have a custom form with a `To` field to add the user and assign the task.

My problem is that when the owner of a task open the task i would like the `To` field to be empty and keep the assigned in another field (as a `Textbox` ). So when a user need to assign the same task to a second user to add the new user in the `To`and when sabe the task to update the `Textbox` and not replace the old value with the new one. This is the code that i have create. I use a button and when click add the value from To field in a `Textbox` but the only that do is to replace the old value with the new one.

```
Sub  add_click ()

 Set objPage = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("Assign Task")
 Set objControl = objPage.Controls("ListBox1")
 Set objassigncheck = objPage.Controls("CheckBox1")
 Set objsend = objPage.Controls("sendtask")
 Set objTo = objPage.Controls("To")
 Set objtest = objPage.Controls("TextBox4")
 Set objcombo1 = objPage.Controls("ComboBox1")

  For i=1 to Item.Recipients.Count
    objtest.Value=Join(Array(Recipients.Item(i)),"; ")
  Next
End Sub
```

Can someone suggest something?

Comment: Tried `objtest.Value = objtest.Value & Recipients.Item(i) & "; "`?

Answer (score 0):

`objtest.Value = objtest.Value & Recipients.Item(i) & "; "?`

> Taken from PatricK's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681780/outlook-textbox-value-update-and-not-replace#comment30995649_20681780) on the question.